# i added Puppetteer with his dependencies for Heroku , and now pushing to heroku is taking while (5/6 minute) for a small app

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, puppeteer

i am using puppetter to generate a pdf from an html page , i added the npm PUPPETTER with this commande

```
npm i puppeteer
```

then  i pushed to heroku but a error occured

```
error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

that why after some research i installed the following buildpack for heroku:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add jontewks/puppeteer
```

the problem is that from now when i push the app its taking alot of time like 5/6 minutes or even more! any ideas ?

Comment: puppeteer requires Chromium (or chrome?) which is a large binary that needs to be uploaded which is about 100-200mb

Comment: do you meen that there. is nothing to do? now i am running with two buildpacks  jontewks/puppeteer and heroku/nodejs can i remove the second one (i sound to me stupid question but i am still asking ;) ) ?  and why its uploading(Chromium) for every push and not only at the first time ? i

Comment: I'm not too familiar with heroku. Ideally you'd deploy your code and have `npm install` run after that so things are downloaded in heroku (which is probably got better bandwith). I don't know how to do this though (or if it's possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after research the best thing for me was to use :

```
npm i puppeteer-core
```

instate of

```
npm i puppeteer
```

because its not charging the whole chrlomium
https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer